# Confusion regarding Newton's Third Law and Conservation of Energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

A specialized system consisting of two bodies A and B. A has 1 J of energy and can thus displace B 1 m by applying a force of 1 N. But at the same time, A also experiences a reaction force and is displaced 1 m also. Then, the total work  done is 2 J. (Note: B had 0 energy). It started with 1 J and ended up with 2 J. How is this possible?

Comment: Agnibho Dutta, remember three rules for collisions:  1) momentum is ALWAYS conserved;  2) total energy is ALWAYS conserved;  3) kinetic energy is conserved ONLY in perfectly elastic collisions.  If the collision is not perfectly elastic, some kinetic energy was "wasted" as sound, deformation of objects, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To say that B experiences a reaction force when A exerts a force on B makes no sense (at least to me). It's A that would experience a reaction force when it exerts a force on B.

This assumes A experiences the reaction force and that A and B move in opposite directions due to the action-reaction pair of forces. Something like two ice skaters  with one pushing on the other with negligible ice friction.

As such, $A$ does $1 J$ of work on $B$ by applying a net force of $1 N$ over $1 m$ on $B$. But $B$ also does $1 J$ of work on $A$ by applying a net force (the reaction force to $A$'s force) of $1 N$ over $1 m$ on $A$. There is no violation of conservation of energy as $A$ and $B$ each do $1 J$ of work on the other for a total of $2 J$ work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If A does positive work on B, as they move together, B does *negative* work on A.

Comment: @JánLalinský I didn't interpret that they move together. I interpreted it that they move in opposite directions. So the direction of each applied force is the same as the direction of the displacement. Like two ice skaters pushing on each other with negligible ice friction.

Comment: Energy is the ability to do work. A had energy but B didn't. I forgot to mention this. So, how come both have 1 J at end.

Comment: B had to have energy in order to transfer energy to A doing work on A. As I pointed out to Jan Lalinsky, I assumed that A and B move in opposite directions, like two ice skaters pushing on each other.

Answer (score 0):

> A specialized system consisting of two bodies A and B. A has 1 J of energy and can thus displace B 1 m by applying a force of 1 N. But at the same time, B also experiences a reaction force and is displaced 1 m also. Then, the total work done is 2 J. (Note: B had 0 energy). It started with 1 J and ended up with 2 J. How is this possible?

It is not possible. Your description is inconsistent. If $A$ has $1\mathrm{\ J}$ energy, say a spring that has been compressed with $1 \mathrm{\ J}$ of energy over a $1 \mathrm{\ m}$ compression, and if $B$ is displaced by the same amount as $A$, then that displacement will be $0.5 \mathrm{\ m}$ each.

Answer (score 0):

> But at the same time, B also experiences a reaction force and is displaced 1 m also [...]

This is incorrect. $\mathrm B$ does not experience the reaction force - $\mathrm A$ does.

So there is no contradiction. If $\mathrm A$ carries kinetic energy (has speed) and impacts $\mathrm B$, then work is done by $\mathrm A$ on $\mathrm B$, which gives $\mathrm B$ a displacement. During the impact, a reaction force by $\mathrm B$ on $\mathrm A$ appears so that work is done by $\mathrm B$ on $\mathrm A$. This work slows down $\mathrm A$ (it is negative), and this corresponds to $\mathrm B$ absorbing some energy (it gains some speed).